# Stata substring error

Tags: stata

I am trying to delete certain substrings from vendor names. So I put in a macro and do this:

```
 local item "BANKOFAMERICA"  " INC" " INCORPORATED" " SYS " " SYSTEMS" " PVT" " PRIVATE"    " LIMITED" " LTD" " LLC" " CORP" "LIMITED LIABILITY" "CORPORATION" " CORP " " COMPANY" " CO " " TECHNOLOGY" " TECH " " GLOBAL"
foreach v in `item' {
replace vendor = subinstr(vendor,"`v'","",.)
}
```

However, this gives me a too few quotes error. I tried compounding the "" around `v' but that didn't work. Any idea what I am doing wrong/another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Your nested quotes are giving you trouble. Your code can be fixed with the addition of some [compound double quotes](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf) in the local macro definition and the replace:

```
local item `" "BANKOFAMERICA"  " INC" " INCORPORATED" " SYS " " SYSTEMS" " PVT" " PRIVATE"    " LIMITED" " LTD" " LLC" " CORP" "LIMITED LIABILITY" "CORPORATION" " CORP " " COMPANY" " CO " " TECHNOLOGY" " TECH " " GLOBAL" "'

foreach v of local item {
    replace vendor = subinstr(vendor,`"`v'"',"",.)
}
```

Alternatively, you can avoid defining the local macro and just use:

```
foreach v in "BANKOFAMERICA"  " INC" " INCORPORATED" " SYS " " SYSTEMS" " PVT" " PRIVATE"    " LIMITED" " LTD" " LLC" " CORP" "LIMITED LIABILITY" "CORPORATION" " CORP " " COMPANY" " CO " " TECHNOLOGY" " TECH " " GLOBAL" {
    replace vendor = subinstr(vendor,"`v'","",.)
}
```

This is not as legible as the first variant.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Dimitriy V. Masterov is fine. This just spells out a key detail.

You can see your error by going

```
. local item "BANKOFAMERICA"  " INC" " INCORPORATED" " SYS " " SYSTEMS" " PVT" " PRIVATE"    " LIMITED" " LTD" " LLC" " CORP" "LIMITED LIABILITY" "CORPORATION" " CORP " " COMPANY" " CO " " TECHNOLOGY" " TECH " " GLOBAL"

. mac li
```

What happens is that the first and last `"` are stripped as delimiters marking the beginning and end of the macro. You must stop that by using compound double quotes first. So far as Stata is concerned `" and "' are matching characters (which can be nested, although that is not needed here).